# Zend Framework 2 Problems with ModuleAutoloader

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2

I am trying to play with ZF2 but I have a problem and I don't know if it's because it is a beta or a configuration problem.

I have taken the zf skeleton from Rob Allen's Blog and following the tutorials:
http://akrabat.com/getting-started-with-zend-framework-2/

When I run my app I have problems in my index:

```
$moduleLoader = new Zend\Loader\ModuleAutoloader($appConfig['module_paths']);
```

I have debugged it and `$appConfig['module_paths']` return a `bool(0)` value which causes this error:

`Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'Invalid path provided; must be a string, received boolean' in C:\wamp\www\test\library\Zend\Loader\ModuleAutoloader.php on line 237`

My configuration is : Windows 7 32bit + wamp (Apache 2.2.21, PHP 5.3.8)

Comment: Download the updated application.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the guide, modules_path is wrapped in a `realpath()` which will return false if the folder doesn't exist. Seems like this is you're problem.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php#refsect1-function.realpath-returnvalues

Comment: The problem is there before i pass this value into the ModuleAutoloader constructor. I tryed at home with the same process ( unzipping, configuring project and apache ) and its work there... i dont understand, ill try to reinstall wamp maybe